# why this always return empty array

Tags: php, laravel

this is my query code for search

```
if ($request->has('search'))
{
    $search = $request->get('search');
    $households = Household::where('data->household_id', 'LIKE', '%$search%')
        ->orWhere('data->data->household->address', 'LIKE', '%' .$search .'%')
        ->orWhere('data->data->members', 'LIKE', '%' .$search.'%')->get();
} else {
    $households = Household::all();
}

if ($households)
{
    return response()->json([
            'error' => false,
            'data'  => HouseholdResource::collection($households),
        ], 200);
}

return "No data found for search";
```

It always return empty array, even data exist in database.

and this is my migration

```
$data = [
        'household_id'   => $request->get('enumeration_id'),
        'data'           => json_encode([
            'household' => [
                'address'=> $request->get('address'),
            ],
            'members'=> [],

        ]),
    ];
```

there is my migration table

```
Schema::create('households', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->uuid('id');
        $table->primary('id');
        $table->string('household_id')->unique();
        $table->jsonb('data');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
```

database data is like

```
"household": {
            "enumeration_id": "1938347-32960066",
            "location": "676 Derick Cape\nReeseburgh, WA 95751",
            "identifier": "122 b 2",
            "location_code": "LK-CMB-002",
            "address": {
                "text": "86242 Lynch Roads\nSouth Deon, KS 16600-5109",
                "village": "address village",
                "district": "address district"
            },
```

Can you got the problem? i need help

Comment: That's not how you join tables and get related data. I'm surprised it's not throwing any errors.

Comment: `'%$search%'` is a literal string anyway.

Comment: what response are you getting in `$households = Household::all();` this case

Comment: So data is a json type in mysql?  I'm pretty sure you mean store/insert, not migration.

Comment: Maybe he's using MongoDB

Comment: i am getting full data @Exterminator

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your table has two columns, household_id and data, of which data is a JSON field, your query should look like:

```
Household::where('household_id', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
        ->orWhere('data->household->address', 'LIKE', '%' .$search .'%')
        ->orWhere('data->members', 'LIKE', '%' .$search.'%')
        ->get();
```

I'm not sure why you're attempting to put everything under another data level.  I also don't think `data->members` will be searchable in this manner based on your provided structure.

Comment: I have changed my code according to yours, but still got the same result

Comment: Well, based on what you've provided, this should match if $search actually matches any of the household ids or addresses, but since I don't know what's in your table and what $search contains, it's not possible for me to verify.

Comment: i have provided database data, but still return empty array. only work for household_id.

Comment: No, you provided the code to insert data, you didn't provide any data.  Actually, not even that, you just provided an array.  I assume that's from the store method.

Comment: please check my post once again

Comment: You can't compare address this way, it's an object.  Search address->text or something.